# modificar el nombre de las columnas de un jtable desde codigo

Tags: java, jframe, jtable

tengo esta tabla en un jframe[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo otro jframe donde al dar click a un botón el jframe donde tengo esta tabla cambia los nombres de las columnas de la tabla, este es el código de la tabla

```
public void desicionmetodos(int a){
    switch (a){
        case 1:
            Object[] columnNames = {"N","Xn","Yn=Xn^2","Xn+1","Rn+1"};
            DefaultTableModel metodocuadradomedio = (DefaultTableModel) TablaUniversal.getModel();
            metodocuadradomedio.addColumn(columnNames);
            TablaUniversal.setModel(metodocuadradomedio);
            break;
    }
}
```

pero al ejecutarlo se ve de la siguiente manera [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con el siguiente fragmento de codigo y me comentas que tal e va :

```
JTableHeader tableHeader = TablaUniversal.getTableHeader();
TableColumnModel tableColumnModel = tableHeader.getColumnModel();
TableColumn tableColumn = tableColumnModel.getColumn(0);
tableColumn.setHeaderValue( "???" );
tableHeader.repaint();
```

Espero te sirva
Saludos.